# ( No module named __main__ ) when using alias in bashrc

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to use alias in treminal, so I opened **.bashrc** 
and write alias in this code

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias censys='python ~/censys-subdomain-finder/censys_subdomain_finder.py --censys-api-id my id --censys-api-secret my secret $1'
```

but when I run it, It give me this error

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/censys", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('censys==0.0.8', 'console_scripts', 'censys')()
  File "/home/momo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/momo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/momo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/momo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named __main__
```

I tried to save it in **.bash_profile** but when I open new trminal, I do not see the alias!
any help please??

Comment: Aliases don't take arguments. Whatever your actual problem is, `censys` should be a function: `censys () { python ...  "$1"; }`.

Comment: The definition does belong in `.bashrc`; it's only useful in interactive shells, each of which will source `.bashrc` on startup, not necessarily `.bash_profile`.

Comment: This problem doesn't look like it has anything to do with aliases *at all*. Typically it means that the code you're invoking is a distutils-generated entrypoint, but in your current scope (with whatever set of virtualenvs &c. are active), the correct version of the associated module isn't installed.

Comment: I'd suggest running `bash -x` before invoking the alias, and comparing the command it logs to whatever manual invocation you can run that works from the same environment/prompt.